# Can't Delete INI File After Calling GetPrivateProfileString

Tags: vb.net, ini

I am having trouble deleting files after calling the GetPrivateProfileString command.  I have the following code:

```
               'Read the INI File
                sb = New StringBuilder(500)
                Select Case FileType
                    Case "Scanner File"
                        res = GetPrivateProfileString("ScannerSetings", "ScannerType", "", sb, sb.Capacity, Filename)
                    Case "Scale File"
                        res = GetPrivateProfileString("ScaleSetings", "ScaleType", "", sb, sb.Capacity, Filename)
                End Select

                'If the result is a value store it, otherwise move it to unprocessed
                If res <> 0 Then InputArray.Add(sb.ToString)

                File.Delete(Filename)
```

After reading the details from the INI file, as soon as I try to delete the file, I am getting the following error: The process cannot access the file 'R:\Drop\011_11_Scanner' because it is being used by another process.

I cannot even delete these files manually until I exit my application.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot even delete these files manually until I exit my application.

This clearly shows that the file that `Filename` points to is locked. As long as it's locked, you won't be able to delete it.

**Check your code for any file handles you have opened (eg for writing purposes) and did not close.**

If you don't close a file after you've opened it, the file is not released and remains in locked state… which practically means it can not be deleted until (a) you close that file-handle, or (b) you close your program, since that's what's holding the file-handle after opening.

**EDIT**

The next thing that comes to mind is that VB.NET may need special user access rights to remove the INI on recent Windows versions. You can quickly cross-check that by simply executing your application with elevated user rights (eg via right-click menu; run as admin). I can't imagine that that's actually the problem — but it's worth a shot. Should it indeed be the problem, check (and modify) the permissions on the folder your application and/or INI resides in.

Comment: Thanks e-sushi for your response.  However, using the GetPrivateProfileString, I'm not actually physically making a call to open the file (unless that's what the stringbuilder does).  Normally I use open and close commands but I haven't needed to on this occasion, so I'm unsure how to close the file if it's been automatically opened.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @user2185200 Added an edit, describing another potential cause of (and solution to) your problem.

Comment: I have ran my application in administrator mode, but it still cannot delete the file.  If I can't get around this, I will have to use another method of reading the file rather than GetPrivateProfileString.  Obviously it calls a process to open the file but never closes it.  As I make no reference to opening it, I don't know how to get a handle to it.

Comment: @user2185200 Well, I'm indeed out of ideas. I have to admit I'm more a C/C++ guy than a VB coder... but it's weird that VB NET actually would keep a file-handle open, as I've never met such a problem using C/C++ when calling GetPrivateProfileString. Hmmm... seems I can't help you after all. Well, at least I tried. Should you ever find out what's causing the issue or how to solve it, don't forget to post it here as an answer to your own question. I bet we're not the only ones wondering about this issue...